# Is it possible to name a property 'StateID' on an entity in EF4.0?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to update an entity in the database using EF4.0 so I'm doing this:

```
_dbctx.AddObject("MyEntities", EntityWithUpdates);
_dbctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(EntityWithUpdates, EntityState.Modified);
_dbctx.SaveChanges();
```

MyEntities has a property named StateID. Using debug I can see the correct value in the StateID property of 217 when it is added to the context, but the value is somehow changed to 0 when ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState completes.

Has anyone seen this before?

This is the only property on the entity having trouble. Should the StateID property name be avoided or is there a work around?

My entity looks like this:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int StateID { get; set; }
}
```

If I get the entity from the database first. Then apply current values everything works wonderfully like this:

```
MyEntity entity = _dbctx.MyEntities.Where(i => i.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
_dbctx.ApplyCurrentValues("MyEntities", EntityWithUpdates);
_dbctx.SaveChanges();
```

This does appear to be an object graph problem, but I still prefer being able to attach the entity and save to avoid the db call.

I looked at several other entities in the application and believe eran otzap is correct. The entire object graph is being saved with includes the State. Because the state isn't loaded EF wants to create it even though it has a valid ID. So it seems the only safe way to apply changes to this entity is to first get it from then db, apply, and then save changes. Bummer.

For anyone else who might see this. eran otzap suggests applying a value for StateID. He said this "might" work. In my situation it did not. I had to get the entity first before EF would recognize the StateID.

Comment: show the entity and how you update it .

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. The model is passed into the method from the controller. i.e. Update(MyEntityModel model). After that I simply map the properties and try to update using automapper. I did find something else. Using SQL Profiler I noticed the StateID value 0 causes EF to create a new State because of the navigation property between MyEntities and States. That's where the 588 value came from in StateID, but I still don't understand why ObjectStateManager changes the property to 0.

Comment: I assume `StateId` is the entity key?

Comment: No, there is an ID property on the entity that is the entity key.

Comment: ok i think i understand . sadly i'm on able to enter Stackoverflow's chat rooms at my work place and it's allot to write 
can we speak on hangouts or something like that ?

eranotz50@gmail.com

Comment: Is there a navigation property with relation to `State` entity?

Comment: Mainly your probably saving an entire object graph with your entity. and you can't control the order in which things are saved. since it does not have a record yet to satisfy your entity's foreign key. what you need to do is a aplay a value of your own to the entity's StateId and give the same value to other entities connected to it by that id. when saving it ef might replace that value by a real one but it will replace it for the entire graph.

Comment: I guess I can see what your saying. The StateID 217 is a valid entity key in States. There is a navigation property to States from MyEntities.

Comment: OK. So there is a navigation property between ID in States and StateID on MyEntities. The value on the model is a valid ID in States. What I can't seem to understand is why Changing the state of the entity would remove the StateID / make it 0. If what eran otzap is saying were happening. Wouldn't I see this when I SaveChanges() is called instead of ObjectStateManager?

Comment: @gummo i didn't understand how you ended up solving this issue ...?
My suggestion was correct for a certain case , maybe i miss understood your situation.

Comment: Hi eran otzap. From a database standpoint the StateID on my entity is the primary key on the State table so there is a relationship in my EF Designer relating the two. When I newed up my entity, applied the ID, and StateID, and saved the model the absent State entity caused it to create a new state in the State table. If I load the entity like this _dbctx.MyEntitites.Where(i => i.ID == id).Include("State").FirstOrDefault() it loads the state entity and there for a new state isn't created when the entity is saved. I'm not sure I understand why exactly, but that appears to be the behavior.

Comment: Why are you using EF4 and not EF6?